# How do you synchronize content between IIS Servers?

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-server, synchronization, xcopy

I just came across this utility that will sync IIS servers and was wondering what other software people are using?

http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy

The company I'm at uses a very old version of Content Management Server 2003 and I'm looking for a supported product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That web deployment tool is good!

Disclosure: MSFT employee, clearly biased!

The Web Deployment Tool can migrate sites and apps between servers, and has some really useful features for determining whether configuration has drifted between servers within a farm.

Generally, you -verb:sync content into a package of some sort, then you can -verb:sync or -verb:migrate that package to an IIS 6.0 or 7.0 target server. If you're just curious, you can -whatif the operation, which will identify all proposed changes between source and target servers.

In my experience, with IIS 6 servers, the key problem that develops over time is that the metabases drift between farm members (unless it was carefully planned and managed from the beginning), and that can lead to - let's call them *interesting* - farm behaviours. This tool can evaluate metabase differences, content differences, the works, with much less effort than trying to script IISCNFG.vbs to achieve the same result. The syntax is a little confronting at first, but the investment is worthwhile, IMHO.

CMS had a separate workflow and deployment engine, as I recall, so it might not have comparable features on the workflow front, but for pushing sites around between servers, and synchronizing farms (both content and settings), I've found WebDeploy is pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

For something that old, running on Windows 2003 (I assume) I'd probably go with robocopy or something similar.

For Windows 2008 servers I use DFS between the servers (for the sites that need it like WordPress).  For sites that where all files are pushed by a sysadmin we just push to each server manually so we keep pull one server out of the load balencer at a time upgrade it, then put them all in pulling the last one down.

Comment: I've also been using DFS (in combination with NLB) on Windows Server 2008 servers. Works very well.